# Difference between System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory and Microsoft.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, msdn

While reading around Active Directory, I come across `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` and `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management`.

What is the difference between `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` and `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management`?

Comment: The `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management` namespace contains code intended for use with PowerShell, whereas the `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` are intended for more general use

Comment: @SandipD - There is no such dll/module as `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory`; the module/dll is instead named as `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management`. I've made the necesssary edit in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already hinted by `@Mathias R. Jessen` in the comments:

> **[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory Namespace:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)**
>
> The System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace provides a high
>   level abstraction object model that builds around Microsoft Active
>   Directory services tasks. The Active Directory service concepts such
>   as forest, domain, site, subnet, partition, and schema are part of the
>   object model.
>
> 1. The System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace is used to automate Active Directory management tasks.
>      System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory is not used to access data
>      that resides within Active Directory or any other directory service.
>      The System.DirectoryServices namespace should be used for this
>      purpose.
> 2. *The System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace is intended for use by application developers* who are **familiar with .NET Framework
>      programming using Visual Basic .NET or C#**.

---

> **[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management:](https://superuser.com/questions/913514/enabling-active-directory-module-for-powershell-via-command-line)**
>
> It is **the Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell**. This is
>   installed when you'll install `Remote Server Administrations Tools` or
>   a subset of this feature
>   (RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell). For management
>   of Microsoft's Active Directory, you should import this module into
>   PowerShell.

Image of `Windows Directory Services API Layers`, as taken from [Active Directory, 5th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023913.do):

[image]